# How to build pipes-and-filters eip pattern with apache-camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration-patterns

I'm trying to do a PoC in order to implement the [pipes and filters eip pattern](http://www.eaipatterns.com/PipesAndFilters.html) with [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).

From [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html), I'm assuming that each filter must be implemented as an [Endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/endpoint.html) ("With Camel you can split your processing across multiple independent Endpoint instances which can then be chained together.")

So, if I understood correctly, the Authenticate filter (from the example) must implement the [Endpoint interface](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Endpoint.html).

The "problem" is that I don't want to "re-invent the wheel". So instead of implementing the interface from the scratch, I'm almost sure that I can use an already implemented one. And the one is the [BeanEndpoint](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/bean/BeanEndpoint.html).

Is that right?

I found a few examples of pipes and filters patterns ([like this one](http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-another-example.html)) but none of then show how to implement the beans.

Can someone provide a bean implementation example?

TIA,

Bob

Comment: There is no need to implement the Bean endpoint to define a pipe with beans. There are examples [here](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html). Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, although I get where you're coming from when you say "camel implements filters as endpoints", I wouldn't strictly classify them as endpoints. More like message transformer/translators in my opinion.

So, in case you need to implement a custom filter as per your requirement, use the [processor interface](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html).

Basically, write a class(say, CustomProcessor) that implements Camel's Processor and write your custom filter strategy. Then, call it in your route as to("CustomProcessor").

The Processor page will surely clear all your concerns, so please have a look.

Also I assume you're aware of the [camel message-filter pattern](http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Camel EIPs is listed here, and they all have examples and whatnot
http://camel.apache.org/eip

So for the pipes and filters you can find it on that link and see some examples
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/pipeline-eip.html

And it seems you are new to Camel. Then I suggest to read this intro article to get your heads around Camel: http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache